# How to get key value from properties file at runtime using spring

Tags: spring, spring-security

I want to get the changed key value from properties file at runtime.

test.properties file:
name = Hi

I have made Thread sleep with 5 sec and changed the key value as "Hello" but it is not getting changed.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:test.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property> 
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:test</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="tempBean" name="tempBean1" class="org.sri.spring.temp.Temp"
    lazy-init="false" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg type="String" value="${name}" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `${name}` placeholder inside the XML configuration is resolved using the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` which, as you may notice, has *nothing* in common with your reloadable `messageSource`.
It wouldn't work either way because Spring instantiates the `tempBean` only once: on application startup, by passing the value of `${name}` to the constructor. The bean itself is not aware of where the value came from (and in particular, it doesn't care if the properties file gets edited).

If you *really* think it's a good idea to do it†, you can inject the entire `messageSource` into your `tempBean`, and get the current value in each call, e.g.:

```java
public class Temp {
  @Autowired // or wired in XML, constructor, etc.
  private MessageSource messages;

  public String sayHello() {
    return messages.getMessage("name", null, Locale.getDefault());
  }
}
```

---

† injecting a configuration-related object makes testing more difficult and is arguably bad design (mixing concerns). Have a look at the [Spring Cloud Config](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/) project as it's likely that this is how the future is going to look like.

Answer (score -1):

I do not think that Spring will update already existing beans when the properties change.

Try to create a new bean (prototype scope)

Comment: He is already doing it. I guess the issue is because he loads it from classpath. Take a look at my answer and let me know if anything incorrect.